# Tests navigator in xcode 7 says (null)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

When I try to test my iOS app the Xcode 7 test navigator shows (null) the second time I run my tests.

The first time it looks normal:

[image]

However, as I run the tests again the 12 tests turn into a single test named (null) and it feels like the test cases aren't really run anymore, they just succeed every time after 1 millisecond.

[image]

I'm using Kiwi for the tests, but it feels more like something going wrong in Xcode7. I don't remember having this problem in Xcode6. The only thing that consistently solves the problem seems to be an Xcode reboot.

Has anyone had this issue as well?

Comment: I have seeing this exact same thing with xcode 7. I am using Specta for my test framework. I found that if you restart xcode it will run the tests once but then not again. Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: For a temporary solution try
1) right click (null) and disable it
2) you should be able to run again now
3) to run a 3rd time (you should see all your test cases with null), run again (won't actually run though)
4) after it says success, enable then disable (null)

Comment: Same issue on Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68)

Answer (score 0):

I have just experienced the same issue. Commenting out the test class name so the test would not build and then putting the test class name back fixed it for me.